# Unpaper only processing first page?

Tags: macos, pdf, imagemagick

I'm trying to use `unpaper` to process some PDFs that I have.

But `unpaper` only seems to process the first page everytime. I'm using Mac OS X Yosemite. Here's my process:

I scan in the document in PD using *Preview.app*. Then, I convert the .pdf file to .pnm by using this ImageMagick command:

```
convert -density 150 document.pdf -depth 8 document.pnm
```

After conversion, I run `unpaper` on the document:

```
unpaper document.pnm output.pnm
```

and convert the output back to PDF

```
convert output.pnm output.pdf
```

However, the output.pdf will only have the first page processed by `unpaper`, and the rest are not even present in the output.

It's not ImageMagick that loses the pages, since running

```
convert document.pnm test.pdf
```

Outputs a PDF file with all of the pages. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If your PDF indeed is a multi-page document, your output file will not be named `document.pnm`. Instead, you will have multiple output files, one per PDF page. They will be named `document-1.pnm`, `document-2.pnm`, etc.

Hence, your further processing has to take this into account...

Finally, whenever you are prepared to convert your PNMs back to PDF, run this command:

```
convert output*.pnm output.pdf
```